# Simulating Inheritance in Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am working on a database, using Sql Server 2012.  In our data model we have a type of `User`, with basic login information, name, address, etc, etc. Some of these users will be `Technician`s, who have all the same properties as a `User`, but some other properties like `Route`, `Ship To Location`, etc.

My question is, in designing a database, how does one simulate this situation. I have thought of 2 options.

1. Have a foreign key in the `Technician` table to the PK of the `User` database to link them up. My worry with this one is how will I know if a user is a technician, I would have to run a query on the technicians table each time a user logs in.
2. Have a field in `User` table link up with the PK of the Technician database, and if this field is null, or -1 or whatever I know this user is not a technician. I dont see any immediate problems with this one, but I am no expert at database design.

Do either of these have an advantage, and if so, why? Currently I have 2 different tables with two completely different id's, and they are not linked in any way, which I am now facing problems because of.

Comment: I *prefer* option #1 because I *try to mitigate the use of nullable FKs*. Hopefully both of these *relations* (aka Tables) are part of the same *database*.

Comment: I would do option #1 and simply `LEFT JOIN` the Technician table, if there is no record all the Technician fields will be NULL in the result. Alternatively, you could also add a field to the User database that tells you this user is a Technician (or other type of user with more fields) so you know to query the Technician table. But that requires 2 queries as well as more overhead in your main code.

Comment: @user2864740 - both tables are part of the same database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lets say you have 3 different sub class type of Class user. you can have a column in User table to identify the subclass Type. for example UserTypeID. if possible values are too many you can create new table to store these userTypes.

UserTypeID

1=Technician

2=Mechanic

3=Accounttant

Edit1

UserTypeID will be exist in all sub class entities.
Also from the other comments I feel lot concerns about getting data out of sync w/o explicit RI constraint. Just wanted to make sure that this column value should not be coming from app code or user instead the sql API inserting record should find out the right value based on which sub class entity is getting the insert record.

For example Pr_InsertUser API insert new technician. This insert API first finds out why I the UserTypeId for technician and insert record in to class user and get userid. Then passes the userId and UserTypeId to subclass technician an call another private sql API Pr_Insert_Technician to insert more attributes.

So the point I am trying to make is as SQL does not support explicit FK from multiple tables to single table that should be taken care in SQL API.

```
    Declare @user Table
    (
        userid          int
        ,UserTypeID     Tinyint
        ,username       sysname
        ,userAddress    sysname
    )

    Declare @Technician Table
    (
        userid      int
        ,UserTypeID Tinyint
        ,attr1      sysname
        ,attr2      sysname
    )

    Declare @Mechanic Table
    (
        userid      int
        ,UserTypeID Tinyint
        ,attr3      sysname
        ,attr4      sysname
    )

    Declare @Accounttant Table
    (
        userid      int
        ,UserTypeID Tinyint
        ,attr2      sysname
        ,attr4      sysname
    )
```

Comment: Note: Storing the `UserIdType` is *denormalized* data that does not necessarily reflect the state of the tables. While it *can* be used as part of RI (by using it as part of a compound FK such that the appropriate table has a matching UserTypeId) I tend to avoid such *discriminators* if possible.

Comment: So this is more like my option 2, where the Primary user key is used referenced in the second table, correct

Comment: @DarylBehrens It's like option #1 (the Technician table has the User FK) that introduces a `UserTypeId` as discriminator. I do not recommend it in general, the core problem being that the duplicate data become "unsynced" without further (and sometimes complex) RI constraints. If such a discriminator may be useful for *queries* then a materialized view can be created to expose such information.

Comment: @DarylBehrens The main point of a discriminator is to try and solve the problem that SQL has of not supporting *distributed* foreign keys (a FK split between multiple tables). If only using an ORM this will be internally used so that - hopefully - an inconsistency should never occur. However, if not using such a heavy-handed ORM, I  find it better to just run the appropriate queries and build the appropriate views w/o a discriminator. Either that, or compound FKs can be created where it is *prohibited* for a User to be a Technician *and* a Mechanic ..

Comment: @user2864740, "the core problem being that the duplicate data become "unsynced" without further (and sometimes complex) RI constraints."  Can you explain bit more what data is duplicating and when it is getting a-sync?

Comment: @AnupShah Imagine if a User has a UserTypeId=Technician and an entry in the Technician table. All is good. Now, the entry in the Technician table is deleted and they have an entry added to the Mechanic table. This isn't necessarily bad/wrong (i.e. using a pure approach #1); however, the discriminator is now *invalid* per the other information in Technician/Mechanic tables. If each one of the Technician/Mechanic tables *also* had a UserTypeId column (which would be a fixed value per table), then then we could establish a (User, UserTypeId) relationship.

Comment: @user2864740 Point1: I did updated my original solution saying that each subclass table will also have UserTypeID. which will be same value per entire subclass table. Point2: When you explain Delete Technician and Insert Mechanic scenario did you assume that that delete/insert will not have done anything in User Class table? because ALL CRUD API would have to make sure that ALL Insert/Update/Delete is propagated to Class User Table as well as appropriate Subclass table. so in this example Delete Technician and Delete User, Insert Mechanic and Insert User.

Comment: @AnupShah Ahhh, I didn't see the edit (it is still not reflected in the schema).

Comment: before I just mentioned in text that all subclass will also have UserTypeID column but now I updated sample schema tables as well. sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to familiarize yourself with the way ORM's do it. 
Even if you don't use an ORM.  It will lay out some of the options.

http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/#inheritance

http://ayende.com/blog/3941/nhibernate-mapping-inheritance

Comment: I think most ORMs do things backwards. Generally, they say: "screw the SQL, use the Object Graph". And, while they can be tremendously useful and do "OO" things (e.g. inheritenace), this often leads to "interesting" uses of RA/SQL. (I write the Schema first, then use a mapper that will deal with it - some ORMs are more accommodating of this approach.)

Comment: I think one should know both sides of the coin, to help pick the final solution.  The opposite of what you said is "we'll deal with the OO later", which can also cause issues and small (or even significant) db redesign issues.......or very difficult ORM "mappings".  A good team considers the needs of the dba and the developer.

Comment: And even though I'm a c# OO developer, i never say "screw the sql".  I pick the "inheritance by" that maps most closely to how i would wire up the sql "by hand".